# what are the difference between static stack and dynamic stack in context of memory management

Tags: memory-management, dynamic, static, stack

1. Size of static storage area is constant throughout execution but dynamic stack grows and shrinks as per push and pop of activation record.
2. Storage requirements known prior to execution in static stack but int dynamic stack The size and structure of a stack frame is known at compile time, but actual contents and time of allocation is unknown until runtime.

What more can be the differences and can anyone help me with a code snippet.
Thank You.

Comment: It's not clear what you are really asking.

Comment: the difference between static stack and dynamic stack, not in context of data structure but memory management.

Comment: Guess part of the problem is, what do you mean by "static stack"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can chime in a bit here since I am currently working on a system that employs a kind of static stack.

Since you mentioned stack frames you must know that the stack is used to keep track of context when you enter deeper-nested subroutines. Just explicitly mentioning this b/c it is relevant in the next paragraph.

Typically the stack and heap are viewed as *dynamic* meaning that they are allowed to expand in size - usually done with memory management along the lines of `malloc()` etc. The [classic illustration is show here (left panel)](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/guides/cropped_images/000/000/342/medium640/Stack_Operation.gif?1534968899). As you can see in the middle panel the stack grows + shrinks in a well-organized manner because memory can only be allocated or freed at the bottom edge. The heap, on the other hand, can see memory allocated / deallocated anywhere internally. A collision will occur when the two areas meet -- this will cause a big problem because no further subroutines can be called. Furthermore it can be hard to predict when this will happen.

If you want to avoid this kind of problem (for instance in a safety-critical application) you might opt to disallow dynamic memory usage in one or both of the stack + heap. A good time to use a static stack is when you are confident that your program will never exceed a particular depth of subroutine calls (e.g. no recursion, or recursion is capped). Using a static stack also simplifies the implementation, which is something that you might be concerned with on bare-metal applications.

The following code is a little example of how a static stack might be implemented in startup code:

```c
//*****************************************************************************
//
// Reserve space for the system stack.
//
//*****************************************************************************
__attribute__ ((section(".stack")))
static uint32_t g_pui32Stack[1024];
```

The `section` attribute allows you to locate the stack in memory with the linker script:

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0000C000, LENGTH = 960K
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 384K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        /* This is where executable code gets stored */
    } > FLASH

    /* User stack section initialized by startup code. */
    .stack (NOLOAD):
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        *(.stack)
        *(.stack*)
        . = ALIGN(8);
    } > SRAM

    .data :
    {
        /* This is where global/static initialized variables are stored */
    } > SRAM AT>FLASH

    .bss :
    {
        /* This is where global/static 0-filled variables are stored */
    } > SRAM

    .heap (COPY):
    {
        /* This is where dynamically allocated storage could be used */
    } > SRAM
}
```

You can see that in this case the stack is not located next to the heap... A static stack can be put wherever you want because the assumption is that you'll never go beyond its boundaries.